# How to tail all lines except first row

Tags: linux, bash

For example, I have a file

```
1
2
3
```

then I want to output from 2nd row to tail

How can I do it in linux

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
tail -n+2 my_file
```

will output all the lines in `myfile` starting with line 2. (`-n2` would show you the last two lines.)

`tail` has lots more options. Type `man tail` for complete documentation.

Comment: BSD allows just `+2`, but this answer works in both GNU and BSD.

Comment: @PaulBissex: GNU tail also still accepts just `+2`, but in both cases the usage has been deprecated for a long time and so I prefer not to use it.

Comment: Beware: `tail` counts from `1`, not from `0` as one (a programmer) might expect!

Answer (score 24):

shorter with

```
$ sed 1d filename
```

or with `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR>1' filename
```