# Merge two .csv files into one and keep just one header - in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have two .csv files in the same directory with the same number of columns and I want to combine them into one file, but keep just one header from the first file. The file name is always different, only the prefix remains the same:

```
orderline_123456.csv

Order_number,Quantity,Price
100,10,25.3
101,15,30.2
```

```
orderline_896524.csv

Order_number,Quantity,Price
102,20,12.33
103,3,3.4
```

The output file should be like:

```
file_load.csv

Order_number,Quantity,Price
100,10,25.3
101,15,30.2
102,20,12.33
103,3,3.4
```

This was already in the shell script file, because since now I needed to take only one file, but now I have to  merge two files:

```
awk '(NR-1)%2{$1=$1}1' RS=\" ORS=\" orderline_*.csv >> file_to_load.csv
```

I tried changing it into

```
awk 'FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {next} (NR-1)%2{$1=$1}1' RS=\" ORS=\" orderline_*.csv >> file_to_load.csv
```

but I get the header twice in the output.

Could you please help me? How exactly should the command look like? I need to keep how it was defined before.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JRichardsz unfortunately, not yet

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **merging** the files?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for

```bash
awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' file ...
```

NR is the count of all records seen, and
FNR is the record number of the current file.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried with "awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1 (NR-1)%2{$1=$1}1' RS=\" ORS=\" orderline_*.csv >> file_to_load.csv" but I still have the header from the second file. I assume maybe it is something in the order of the commands or I don't write them corectly?

Comment: What is this: `(NR-1)%2`? Why are you doing something for every 2nd line?

Comment: @Cristina096 : Please put such a long piece of code into your question, not into a comment. It is hard to read, in particular if you don't format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is divide the task in easy steps

#### 1. Get the first line which is the header and store as variable

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439587/3957754

[image]

```
header=$(head -n 1 file1.csv)
```

#### 2. Get all lines of a file except the first one

[How to tail all lines except first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504311/how-to-tail-all-lines-except-first-row)

```
body=$(tail -n+2 file1.csv)
```

Repeat this for both files

[image]

#### 3. Concat the header and n bodies

csv_merger.sh

```
header=$(head -n 1 file1.csv)
body1=$(tail -n+2 file1.csv)
body2=$(tail -n+2 file2.csv)
echo "$header" > merged.csv
echo "$body1" >> merged.csv
echo "$body2" >> merged.csv
```

Result

[image]

You could extend this script to handle more files

Comment: In case of big files it might not be a good idea to store the output in variables. Better redirect it to the output file: `head -n 1 file1.csv > merged.csv` `tail -n+2 file1.csv >> merged.csv` etc.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Using [`csvstack`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvstack.html) from the handy [csvkit package](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is one way to merge CSV files with the same columns:

```bash
$ csvstack orderline_123456.csv orderline_896524.csv > file_load.csv
```